# Как сделать offset на AVAudioPCMBuffer?

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation

У меня есть `AVAudioPCMBuffer`, который используется для `AVAudioPlayerNode` для воспроизведения

```
    internal func play() {
        guard let buf = pcmBuf else {
            logger?.log(severity: .error, msg: "Sound pcmBuf is nil.")
            return
        }
        
        if !isPlaying {
            player.scheduleBuffer(buf, at: nil, options: .loops)
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно сделать, чтоб была возможность `seek()` вперед, я кажется, что это должно быть сделано с помощью `offset` на `AVAudioPCMBuffer`, вроде такого

```
    internal func play() {
        guard let buf = pcmBuf else {
            logger?.log(severity: .error, msg: "Sound pcmBuf is nil.")
            return
        }

        buf.offset = 10 // Eg: in sec        

        if !isPlaying {
            player.scheduleBuffer(buf, at: nil, options: .loops)
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

то есть берем дату которая уже есть говорим сделай офсет на 10 секунд и установи заново, но нет такого метода `offset`

Как это сделать?

**P.S.**

То есть флоу такой `native lib -> UnsafeRawPointer -> convert in pcm buf -> use in the node`

**P.P.S.**

Я знаю, что такого метода не существует, не нужно писать это в ответах. Вопрос скорее про то как это решить? У меня была идея допустим брать поинтер на дату и записывать в файл и потом читать с файла, но это выглядит совсем криво.

Comment: да судя по документации нет такого метода https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiopcmbuffer, если есть исходники реализации этого класса можно было бы глянуть туда для уверенности.

Comment: @DaniilLoban нет сомнения в том, что такого метода нет (я это указал в вопросе), но как это сделать? Мне не вериться, что нет возможности сделать `seek` если ты не работаешь с файлом.

Comment: файл и аудиобуфер мне кажутся разными понятиями, условно говоря от качества записи будет зависеть сколько байт нужно перескочить, возможно стоит поискать другую библиотеку с реализованной перемоткой

Comment: @DaniilLoban `AVFoundation` это базовый iOS фреймворк которые позволяет работать со звуком, в любом случае любые кастомные либы будут основываться на нем. Так что даже если там это будет значит как то они это сделали с помощью этого фреймворка.

Comment: в таком случае я бы смотрел сорцы, сам к сожалению не на маке, но может есть что-то в гите

Comment: Вот: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/memorylayout/2996397-offset

Comment: Или это: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-adjust-the-position-of-a-view-using-its-offset